# unity - get component variable from object in trigger

Tags: unity

i want to get a component value from the game object which collides with my trigger's object script. this is my code on the trigger:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider obj){
     if(obj.GetComponent<motor>().enabled == true){
         passed = true;
     }
 }
```

and this is the error i get:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 cp.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider obj) (at Assets/Scripts/cp.cs:15)
```

also when changing the code on the trigger:

```
 motor mObj = obj.gameObject.GetComponent();
    if(mObj != null){
         //code here
         Debug.Log("mObj not null");
     }else{
             Debug.Log("mObj is null");
     }
```

it returns

> mObj is null

but the parent obj does have that 'motor' script, other scripts in the car which enter the trigger can access it

Comment: <motor> is case sensitive?

Comment: the script name is all lowercase @dnkdrone.vs.drones

Comment: try "motor m = obj.GetComponent<motor>();"

Comment: tred that: 'code' motor mObj = obj.gameObject.GetComponent();
    if(mObj != null){
         //code here
         Debug.Log("mObj not null");
     }else{
             Debug.Log("mObj is null");
     }    'code'  returned 'code' mObj is null 'code'

Answer (score 3):

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider obj){
     if(obj.GameObject.GetComponent<motor>().enabled == true){
         passed = true;
     }
 }
```

adding this GameObject --> obj.GameObject.GetComponent().enabled would just work :)

let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to the code.

```
    motor mObj = obj.gameObject.GetComponent<motor>(); 
    if(mObj != null){
         //code here
         Debug.Log("mObj not null");
     }else{
             Debug.Log("mObj is null");
     }
```

On trigger will only work if the game object to which this script is attached have a collider. It won't work if only the children have colliders.

Comment: returns "mObj is null"

Comment: the object to enter the trigger is a car with only a colder on its body (currently just a cube) and wheel collides, would the wheel collides be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i found that it must be the wheel collides or some other child causing the issue anyway here is the code i now use

```
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider obj){


    motor mObj = obj.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<motor>();
    if(mObj != null){
        //code here
        Debug.Log("mObj not null");
        if(mObj.enabled == true){
            Debug.Log("cp passed");
        passed = true;
        }
    }else{
        Debug.Log("mObj is null");
    }

}
```

thank you for helping